# How can I order results by conditions in Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

How can I order results with the Doctrine Query Builder so that the results matching the first condition go first, then the results of the second condition (and all results should be matching the third condition)?

Here is an example of the query:

```
$QB->select('k', 'k.word')
        ->from($repository, 'k')
        ->where('k.word LIKE :strict')
        ->orWhere('k.word LIKE '.':loose')       
        ->andWhere('k.status=1')
        ->setMaxResults(5)
        ->setParameter('strict', $query.'%')
        ->setParameter('loose', '%'.$query.'%');
```

I tried to play with `orderBy()` but it didn't work out - don't know what syntax could be....

**Upd.** Example list of data and result:
Let's say I have a list of data:

- Word:*Car*, Status: *1*
- Word:*Carwash*, Status: *1*
- Word:*Electric    car*, Status: *1*
- Word:*Cartography*, Status:    *1*
- Word:*Cabriolet*,    Status: *0*

And the search query is **"ca"**.

I want the query to order and show these results first:

- Word:*Car*, Status: *1*
- Word:*Carwash*, Status: *1*
- Word:*Cartography*, Status: *1*

Then this result:

- Word:*Electric car*, Status: *1*

And filter out this one, because the status is *0*:

- Word:*Cabriolet*, Status: *0*

Comment: Did you use orderBy or OrderBy?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `orderBy` - corrected the original post

Comment: Can you provide an list of an example entries and how you would expect them to be sorted?

Comment: I have added an example to the post

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
$QB->select('k', 'k.word')
        ->from($repository, 'k')
        ->where('k.word LIKE :strict')
        ->orWhere('k.word LIKE '.':loose')       
        ->andWhere('k.status=1')
        ->setMaxResults(5)
        ->setParameter('strict', $query.'%')
        ->setParameter('loose', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orderBy('k.word', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Yes, that merely orders the records in the alpha-numeric order (0-9,a-z)